# Can I display Styler object (table) in Dash?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I converted a Pandas table to Styler object (with red text) which I would like to display in Dash app.

```
def table_creator(df):

    red_df = df.data.to_dict("records")
    return dash_table.DataTable(red_df,
                                [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                                id = "table")
    
# DASH app.
app.layout = html.Div([
     html.Div([
        table_creator(some_empty_table),
    ]),
   ])
    
                   

@app.callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    Input('submit-button-state', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call = True)

def function_1():
    updated_table = table_creator(real_data_table)
    return updated_table
```

When executing the code above, I get:
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please add a full code, to be able to help you.

Comment: what is `real_data_table`?

Comment: I tried `df.data.to_dict("records")` in my machine, and it works. I think you need to provide me with the sample of the data you have.

Comment: Also, please copy and paste the entire error log to see in which line the error is.